# How to perform a line by line and character by character diff on text?

Tags: c#, text, diff

How do I compare 2 files, and produce a report showing the lines that contain differences, and which characters on those lines are different?

Obviously, there are tools out there to do this already, but I would like to know how this is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx) sample that might help.